# How to replace svg with png?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app, it uses Applayout.razor component as a logo.

How can I use my own wwwroot/images/mylogo.png instead of the svg image?

Applayout.razor:

```
<svg width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="Group 2">
        <g id="flex">
            <path id="Combined Shape" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
...
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason not to use `IMG` tag? Something like this `<img src="/images/mylogo.png" />`

Comment: No reasons, but I have asked perhaps a better solution exists :-). Will check

Comment: Yes, it works, but in Blazor need to use extended path to content. Thnx.